# Still don't understand apt-key deprecation solution

Tags: apt

I've been using ubuntu for years, but for the life of me still cannot understand how to resolve the `apt-key deprecated` warning. I know this question has been asked before and I apologize, but all the solutions I've found are either inconsistent or incomplete. Does anyone have a link to a good walkthrough?

Comment: ... And not a bug.

Comment: Still don't understand. Mostly just breaking my machine at this point trying to figure it out lol

Comment: *What* exactly don't you understand in the existing posts?